# Count occurrences of value in a set of variables in R (per row) - with weights

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, apply

I have the following df8 dataframe:

```
df8=data.frame(V1=c(10,20,10,20),V2=c(20,30,20,30),V3=c(20,10,20,10))
```

Here is the count of occurrences of values per each row:

```
a<-apply(df8,MARGIN=1,table)

> a
[[1]]

10 20 
 1  2 

[[2]]

10 20 30 
 1  1  1 

[[3]]

10 20 
 1  2 

[[4]]

10 20 30 
 1  1  1
```

I have a vector - `V = (0.25,0.25,0.5)`
It means that I would like to multiple each number of occurrences for each row by the vector `V` for each row:
I want to get something like this for calculating (summing the weights of the columns per each distinct row value):
    [[1]]

```
   10  20 
 0.25  0.5

[[2]]

   10   20  30 
 0.5 0.25 0.25 

[[3]]

 10     20 
 0.25  0.5

[[4]]

 10   20   30 
 0.5 0.25 0.25
```

And now I would like to choose for each line the item with the highest `a*V` value:

```
> df8
  V1 V2 V3 max_val
1 10 20 20   20
2 20 30 10   10
3 10 20 20   20
4 20 30 10   10
```

Comment: `a * V`?  No way that worked with an atomic `V`

Comment: It is just an Illustrative example. I want to count the weights of each value by its weights vector and find the max sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be apply `table` function to each row and find out occurrence for value in each column. The factors defined in `V` will then be applied to each column to find index of column with max `freq*V` value. The value from that `index` of that row values will be the desired value.

```
#Multiplier for occurrence in each column
V = c(0.25,0.25,0.5)

#data frame
df8=data.frame(V1=c(10,20,10,20),V2=c(20,30,20,30),V3=c(20,10,20,10))

# This function accepts all columns for a row. Finds frequencies for each
# column values and then multiply with V (column wise)
# Finally value in row at index with max(freq*V) is returned.

find_max_freq_val <- function(x){
  freq_df <- as.data.frame(table(x))
  freq_vec <- mapply(function(y)freq_df[freq_df$x==y,"Freq"], x)
  #multiply with V with freq and find index of max(a*V)
  #Then return item at that index from x
  x[which((freq_vec*V) == max(freq_vec*V))]

}

# call above function to add an column with desired value
df8$new_val <- apply(df8, 1, find_max_freq_val)

df8
#  V1 V2 V3 new_val
#1 10 20 20      20
#2 20 30 10      10
#3 10 20 20      20
#4 20 30 10      10
```

Comment: `apply(df8,1,max)`

Comment: @Onyambu.  Correct. That can be even better.

Comment: Thanks @MKR, But please pay attention that I don't need the max no. of occurrences but the number multiplied by the vector - V.

Comment: @MKR, I get wrong results: > df8
  V1 V2 V3 max_val
1 10 20 20    10.0
2 20 30 10     7.5
3 10 20 20    10.0
4 20 30 10     7.5

Comment: V <-list(0.25,0.25,0.5).  In line 2 -you print 15, for instance, it is wrong! I need to get 30 etc...

Comment: @Avi Have another look at updated answer. Solution should work now.

Comment: I get an error: Error in t(df8) * V : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: In addition, the answer for the 2nd and 4th row is wrong. Please see my question example.

Comment: V relates to the columns, i.e. 0.25 to V1, 0.25 to V2 and 0.5 to V3.  Not to the order of occurrences.

Comment: @Avi I think, I was confused with expected value shown in question in initially. I have modified my answer per the logic described by you. In new solution `table` is applied row-wise. Have a look.